# Kivy: scroll to zoom

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Is there a way to zoom into an image on a desktop kivy app (e.g. zoom with a mouse scroll-wheel)? It appears to be discussed here: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3563 but I do not see if there was a work around given.

I began with a static image in my kivy app. I want to add the ability to zoom / pan into the image. I do not want the actual size of the image frame to change, just add zoom/pan functionality, like you might expect from interacting with google maps for example.

**Possible Programming Directions**

From what I've read, I should be using Scatter(?), and I see that I can manually set the Scatter scale to size up/down the image.

My initial thoughts are that I will have to add a separate widget with a scrollview to contain the scatter layout and that will keep the image frame a consistent size. Then I will need to add an event that dynamically changes the scale value.

**The problems**

- I cannot find the appropriate event to use to change the scale value. the `on_motion` event seemed promising. My app can update values with a slider, but when I try a similar approach using `on_motion,` I get `AttributeError: motion` errors
- I am struggling to create the widget. Most documentation seems to use `.add_widget(...)` in the python file. Is it possible to do this from the kv file? I imagine this process is similar to screens and the screen manager, but I am struggling to find an approach that works.
- **Is there a more straight forward way to do this?**

Is there a way I can use `on_motion` type event in my kv file to adjust this value using the mouse scroll-wheel?

I give a watered down example of the structure of my kivy app - along with what I tried to do to add Scatter. I think I will need to put it into it's own widget to keep the image the same size?

**Toy Example**

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window


kivy.require('1.1.0')

from kivy.app import App

presentation = Builder.load_file("scatter.kv")
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        return presentation

    # def foo():
    #    print("You've reached foo")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
GridLayout:
    cols: 2

    Scatter:
        scale: 5
        # on_motion: root.foo()
        Image :
            source: 'foo.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True

    Button:
        text: 'Hello World'
```

Produces:
[image: screenshot]

Kind of Related:

- [Scatter Covers whole display kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925919/scatter-covers-whole-display-kivy) (Unanswered)
- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3563

Comment: Have never understood `Scatter` or `ScatterLayout`, but you can use `Window.bind(on_motion=on_motion)` in your `app.build()` method to get scrolling events in an `on_motion()` method. Or, better yet, you can put the bind command in a custom Layout widget, and use an instance `on_motion` method.

Comment: Please refer to my solution at [detect mouse wheel scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896086/kivy-python3-detect-mousewheel#)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To achieve my goal, I used a combination of the information in [kivy python3 detect mousewheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896086/kivy-python3-detect-mousewheel#), as pointed out ikolim, and the code given here: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Draggable-Scalable-Button

To keep my answer brief, here's the minimalistic object that extends Scatter object.

```py
class ResizableDraggablePicture(Scatter):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # Override Scatter's `on_touch_down` behavior for mouse scroll
        if touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
            if touch.button == 'scrolldown':
                if self.scale < 10:
                    self.scale = self.scale * 1.1
            elif touch.button == 'scrollup':
                if self.scale > 1:
                    self.scale = self.scale * 0.8
        # If some other kind of "touch": Fall back on Scatter's behavior
        else:
            super(ResizableDraggablePicture, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

The layout is slightly different and I changed the text on the button, but the functionality of my code can be seen in the following gif:

[image: demo of zooming and panning]

For anybody wanting to see my entire toy project to adapt for their own purposes, the entire code is on my github: https://github.com/melissadale/Learning-Kivy/tree/master/ZoomPanning

**UPDATE** my code has been edited to be far more correct from an object-orientated approach, and so I could not reject the edits with a clear conscience. However, when I was first starting with kivy, I would have found this code confusing. If you want to just see the simple version that you can apply directly to verify the relevant, this is my original code:

```
    if touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
    if touch.button == 'scrolldown':
        print('down')
        ## zoom in
        if self.scale < 10:
            self.scale = self.scale * 1.1

    elif touch.button == 'scrollup':
        ## zoom out
        print('up')
        if self.scale > 1:
            self.scale = self.scale * 0.8
```

Answer (score 4):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50123706/8472976) by @mdoc-2011 has the problem that it doesn't anchor onto the mouse pointer, meaning that it is quite annoying to use, since the content will scroll around a lot. This can be fixed by not using the `.scale` property and instead directly calling `apply_transform`:

```
if touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
    factor = None
    if touch.button == 'scrolldown':
        if self.scale < self.scale_max:
            factor = 1.1
    elif touch.button == 'scrollup':
        if self.scale > self.scale_min:
            factor = 1 / 1.1
    if factor is not None:
        self.apply_transform(Matrix().scale(factor, factor, factor),
                             anchor=touch.pos)
```

This version also uses the`.scale_(min/max)` properties, and instead of `1.1` and `0.8` uses `1/1.1` which will make it more intuitive to scroll in an out.