# Kivy : zoom image on Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

Can someone post a working example of how can I zoom in and out an image on android for any Kivy app?

Comment: Use this Github Library how it will match your requirements https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout

Comment: Hi. I can't figure how can I use this to Kivy application. Can you help me?

Comment: Here is a `Kivy` approach [scroll to zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807052/kivy-scroll-to-zoom)

Comment: Have you tried this approach to android? It works on windows but on android?